# Getting value from rails params ajax nested subform (cocoon) with an unknown id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I have a nested form (1-m) in Rails using Cocoon and I'm posting back some details via an ajax call, and I'm unsure how to get the value out of the params, given the index is randomised.

the params in console looks like this:

```
other_request[other_request_details_attributes][0][leave_type_id]:17
```

if I *hard code* the [0] element in the controller I get the output I want i.e.

```
params[:other_request][:other_request_details_attributes]["0"][:leave_type_id]
```

How do I read out the leave_type_id value when the [0] element can be a random number?

Comment: Do you want to be able to do this in the controller (in ruby) or in javascript, when you prepare your ajax query?

Comment: @nathanvda I'd be happy either way, ultimately I need the "17" in the controller to work with, the rest is not required.

Comment: Safest option here seems to be using hash.dig params.dig(:other_request).dig(:other_request_details_attributes)&.values&.dig(0, :leave_type_id)